# Распарсить строку на массивы по пробелам

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

В массиве $a[0] есть такая строка

> 739847692892592947 732607245916919875 731940430500944768 730650969263659508 721738363475941480

Как мне распределить каждый блок цифр, разделенных пробелами в массивы `$b[0],$b[1],$b[2]` и т.д? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

.

```
$b = explode(' ', $a[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "739847692892592947 732607245916919875 731940430500944768 730650969263659508 721738363475941480";

preg_match_all('|(\d+)|is', $str, $match);

var_dump($match[1]);

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "739847692892592947"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "732607245916919875"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "731940430500944768"
  [3]=>
  string(18) "730650969263659508"
  [4]=>
  string(18) "721738363475941480"
}
```

Comment: Кто такой умный минуса лепит?

Comment: Я не минусовал, но решение слишком сложное

Comment: Решенте нормальное. Альтернативное и возможное